# Why is there a error "Cannot Allocate Memory" while creating message queue in POSIX?

Tags: c, linux, posix, ipc, message-queue

Why is there a error "Cannot Allocate Memory" while creating message queue in POSIX?

Comment: what is the code you are using to try to create it?

Comment: Wild guess, but maybe your system couldn't allocate enough memory when you're creating a message queue (Perhaps you pass some wrong arguments when you create the queue, show that code)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Adrian's answer is correct, but since this is a frustratingly common error to run into on Linux when first attempting to use POSIX message queues for anything non-trivial, I thought I'd add some helpful particulars.

First, to understand the `RLIMIT_MSGQUEUE` resource limit, see the formula at `man setrlimit`:

> RLIMIT_MSGQUEUE (Since Linux 2.6.8)
>   Specifies the limit on the number of bytes that can be allocated for POSIX message queues for the real user ID of the calling process. This limit is enforced for mq_open(3). Each message queue that the user creates counts (until it is removed) against this limit according to the formula:

```
bytes = attr.mq_maxmsg * sizeof(struct msg_msg *) +
        attr.mq_maxmsg * attr.mq_msgsize
```

> where attr is the mq_attr structure specified as the fourth argument to mq_open(3).
>   The first addend in the formula, which includes sizeof(struct msg_msg *) (4 bytes on Linux/i386), ensures that the user cannot create an unlimited number of zero-length messages (such messages nevertheless each consume some system memory for bookkeeping overhead).

Given the default MQ settings (`mq_maxmsg` = 10, `mq_msgsize` = 8192) on Linux, the above formula works out to only about 10 message queues for the default limit of 819200 bytes. Hence why you will run into this problem as soon as you e.g. forget to close and unlink a couple of queues once done with them.

To raise the `RLIMIT_MSGQUEUE` resource limit to the maximum allowed for the user, you can use something like the following in your application's startup code:

```
#ifdef __linux__
    // Attempt to raise the resource limits for POSIX message queues to
    // the current hard limit enforced for the current real user ID:
    struct rlimit rlim = {RLIM_INFINITY, RLIM_INFINITY};
    const int rc = getrlimit(RLIMIT_MSGQUEUE, &rlim);
    if (rc == 0 && rlim.rlim_cur != rlim.rlim_max) {
      rlim.rlim_cur = rlim.rlim_max;
      setrlimit(RLIMIT_MSGQUEUE, &rlim);
    }
#endif
```

If you also ensure that you set the `mq_maxmsg` and `mq_msgsize` attributes to lower values when opening a queue (see `man mq_open`), you may be able to get away with a couple of hundred queues even within the constraints of the default `RLIMIT_MSGQUEUE` hard limit. Depending on your particular use case, of course.

Adjusting the `RLIMIT_MSGQUEUE` hard limit is not difficult if you have root access to the system. Once you've figured out what the limit ought to be, adjust the system-wide settings in `/etc/security/limits.conf`. For example, to set a hard and soft limit of 4 megabytes for the `www-data` user group, and no limitation for the superuser, you'd add the following lines to the file:

```
@www-data   -   msgqueue    4194304
root        -   msgqueue    unlimited
```

Comment: Another pitfall: Take care to calculate the bytes needed for the setrlimit not only for one queue, but for all queues if you use more than one.

Answer (score 5):

The most likely cause is that you've asked for a message queue bigger than the allowed space. The system limits are controlled in `/proc/sys/fs/mqueue/`. There is also a per user limit (`RLIMIT_MSGQUEUE`) which controls the total number of bytes that a single user can allocate. To check settings on your system, look at the value of `ulimit -q`, which defaults to 819200 bytes.

The developers consider message queues as suitable for small, low-latency messages. It's difficult to distribute an application that uses larger message queues, as system administration changes are required to lift the limits.